# JavaScript Prototype properties initialized in constructor does not overrides with new prototype assigned

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
function ChildClass() {
    **ChildClass.prototype.Field1 = "Field1 value";**
}

ChildClass.prototype = {};

var childInstance = new ChildClass();
print(childInstance.Field1);
```

Why we still have access to childInstance.Field1?

Comment: It's not clear what is confusing about this; the constructor function does run when you use it with `new`.

Comment: How can someone be asking questions about prototyping when they don't even understand something as basic as this?  I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor is adding the property. When you call the constructor to make a new instance, the field is added to the prototype.

Comment: ... which could be bad if the value was mutable, since instance will share a reference but reinitialize it every time.

Answer (score 2):

Because you set that property on the prototype from inside the constructor, which runs after `ChildClass.prototype = {};`.